# Power Automate Approval Flow - Response provided in app - How to end Approval

Tags: workflow, power-automate, powerapps-forms, approval, notifications

I have an Approval workflow (Power Automate) that gets sent to a Project Manager when a user submits a new item.  If the Approver provides a response in either Teams, or the Email notification, the Approval logs that response, and ends accordingly.  BUT, I also include a link to the PowerApps form, where that Approver can also either Reject or Approve the request (via choice field).  When that scenario happens, the Approval flow just sits there still waiting on a response.  The flow is a simple two step process with Create and Approval, then Wait for an Approval.  How can I tell the flow to register either Approved or Rejected if the response is given in the PowerApps choice field (ProjectManagerApprovalChoice), as opposed to directly in the Teams/Email approval notification?

Thank you!